# jQuery if condition not working

Tags: jquery

The if...else  in the line 44 is not working. I checked the value returned by jQuery post and it is returning either 'Y' or 'N'. I am testing this condition and perform some tasks based on the value returned. But that part is not working, neither the alert inside if is working nor the show event in else is working. Unable to find mistake.

```
<?php
    require_once('Connections/met.php');
    session_start();
    include('include/wbc_menu_select.php');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!-- DW6 --><head>
    <!-- Copyright 2005 Macromedia, Inc. All rights reserved. -->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Environmental Survey Laboratory: : Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home_style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/wbc.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery.noConflict();

      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#tldno').focus();
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({    yearRange: "-60:-18",  changeMonth: true,      changeYear: true, dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", altFormat:"yy-mm-dd",altField:"#stddate"   });
     jQuery('#submit').hide();

     });


    jQuery("#tldno").change(function(){


                var rep_sel=jQuery("[name='unit']:checked").val();
                 var name = rep_sel.concat(jQuery("#tldno").val());

               jQuery.post("tld_search_hpu.php", {"name":name},  function(data) { 


    if(data=='Y'){alert("Data Exists"); }
     else{    jQuery('#submit').show();  }

     });

        });


    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
     .wbcmenu{
     vertical-align:middle;
     padding-top:100px;
     height:200px;

     }

     .opt_tbl{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width:auto;
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color:#000066;
        margin-top:-75px;

    }


    #countdata{
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    border:solid;

    }

    #personaldata{

    background-color:#FFFF99;
    color:#FF0000;
    font-size:12px;

    }

    .new{
    border-collapse: collapse;
        width:auto;
        font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color:#000066;
        }

    .new td {
    padding:5px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:left;
    }
    .titl{
    color:#CC0033;
    }

    .na{
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#FF0066;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    fieldset{
        width:500px;

         border:1px solid green

        }


    label {
      float:left;
      width:50%;
      margin-right:0.5em;
      padding-top:0.2em;
      text-align:right;
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size:12px;
      height:20px;

       }
       input {
      font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    div.ui-datepicker{
     font-size:12px;
    }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- DO NOT MOVE! The following AllWebMenus linking code section must always be placed right AFTER the BODY tag-->
    <!-- ******** BEGIN ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR wbcmenu ******** -->
    <script type="text/javascript">var MenuLinkedBy="AllWebMenus [4]",awmMenuName="wbcmenu",awmBN="766";awmAltUrl="";</script><script charset="UTF-8" src=<?php echo '"'.$menu_script.'"';?> type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">awmBuildMenu();</script>
    <!-- ******** END ALLWEBMENUS CODE FOR wbcmenu ******** -->
    <div id="main"> 
    <div id="masthead"></div>
    <!-- end masthead -->
    <div id="content">
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <br/>
    <br/>

      <?php

    if (isset($_SESSION['EMPNO'])){
    $user_type=$_SESSION['wbc_user_type'];
    $user_section=$_SESSION['wbc_user_section'];
    $user_unit=$_SESSION['wbc_user_unit'];
    $user_admin=$_SESSION['wbc_admin'];
    }
    else
    {
    header('Location:wbc_login.php');
    exit();
    }
    ?>




    <div id="pers_form">


    <br/>
    <br/>

    <form id="personnel_data">
    <fieldset >
    <legend> Personnel Data</legend>

    <label for "kgsunit">Select KGS Unit </label><input name="unit" type="radio" value="1" <?php if($user_unit=='1'){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?>/> 1&amp;2<input name="unit" type="radio" value="3"  <?php if($user_unit=='3'){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?> /> 3&amp;4<input name="unit" type="radio" value="6"  <?php if($user_unit=='6'){echo 'checked="checked" ';}?> /> 5&amp;6<br/>
    <label for "tld">TLD No. </label>
     <input type="text" id="tldno" name="tldno" size="25" maxlength="25" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/><br/>

     <label for "fname">Full Name</label><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" size=30 maxlength=30onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keycode=9;"/><br/>

     <label for "dob">Date of Birth</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"  /><input type="hidden" id="stddate" name="stddate" value="<?php echo $dateus; //echo date('d-m-Y');  ?>"/><br/>

     <label for "cat"> Category</label><input name="cat" type="radio" value="R" checked="checked" />
            Regular
            <input type="radio" name="cat" value="C" />Casual<br/>
     <div id="emp"><br/><label for "ccno">CC No.</label><input type="text" name="ccno" value="0" size=25 maxlength=25 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/><br/>
     <label for "empno">Employee No.</label><input type="text" name="empno" value="0" size=25 maxlength=25 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/></div><br/>
     <label for "section">Section</label><select name="section">
              <?php 
        $db=mysql_select_db($database_met,$met) or die("could not connect");
    $secsql= "SELECT *
               FROM sections
               ORDER BY secname; 
                 ";
      $result_sec=@mysql_query($secsql) or die(mysql_error());
                                echo'<option value="" selected="selected">Select Section</option>';
                                while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result_sec))
                                        { echo($row2['secname']);
                                        echo"<option>".$row2['secname']."</option>";}



        ?>
            </select>
        <label for "height"> Height in cm</label><input type="text" name="height" value="0" size=25 maxlength=25 onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;"/></td>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add record" /></td>


    </form>



    </div>






    <br />


    </div>
    <p>
      <!--end content -->
    </p>
    <p>
    <div id="navBar"></p><?php include('cssmenu.php');?> </div>


    <!--end navbar -->
    <div id="siteInfo"><?php include('footer.php');?>  </div>
    <br />
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If neither if/else block is called then i guess your ajax request doesn't succed...

Comment: You need to put the `$("#tldno").change()` call inside `$(document).ready`. Otherwise the element isn't in the DOM when that code runs.

Answer (score 1):

Add some formatting for everyone's sanity. Also, look at where I placed the console.log and it should help you figure out exactly what to put in the if statement.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#tldno').focus();
  jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({    
    yearRange: '-60:-18',  
    changeMonth: true,      
    changeYear: true, 
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
    altFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
    altField:"#stddate"   
  });
  jQuery('#submit').hide();
});

jQuery("#tldno").change(function(){
  var rep_sel=jQuery("[name='unit']:checked").val();
  var name = rep_sel.concat(jQuery("#tldno").val());

  jQuery.post('tld_search_hpu.php', {name: name}, function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
    if (data === 'Y') {
      alert("Data Exists"); 
    } else {
      jQuery('#submit').show();  
    }
  });
});
```